# Looking for lightweight document description language for printing

Tags: c, printing, markup

I'm looking for a very lightweight document description language, which can be easyly parsed in C. The purpose is printing of small documents or labels similar to cash register receipts. I need only basic formatting features for font settings, alignment and insertion of predefined variables.

Any ideas?
Would using of some subset of rtf be a good choice?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has defined a [Report Definition Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Report_Definition_Language) designed for small reports, receipts, and such. Visual Studio can create RDL files, but it is an open standard and there are open source implementations of RDL report generators.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say go for something XML-based (plenty of good fast premade parsers, including for plain C), and probably a tiny subset of XHTML Transitional so as not to reinvent the wheel - `<font name="..." color="...">` and such. RTF is not really much easier to parse, but is very human unfriendly.

Comment: Well, using XML means inventing my own description language on the basis of XML. That's what i wanted to avoid!

Comment: As pointed out, you can just reuse parts of XHTML that you want. I don't think you would find a turnkey solution for this, considering your (rather specific) requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to have a look at the [gd library](http://www.boutell.com/gd/). Just create a simple script language yourself with one GD command per line.

Answer (score 0):

Would also vote for XML and maybe XPS, if your needs are more advanced

Answer (score 0):

Why not [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/), the markup language of Stackoverflow?